# Wait till winform loads before performing next action?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, reporting, wait

Winform application contains one form with a reportViewer control.  When the form is initialized the report is generated but when I try to programmatically run a PrintDialog on the reportviewer I get a 'Operations is not valid due to the current state of the object' error message.

When I comment out the PrintDialog line the report form shows fine.  I think the problem is a lag as it generates the form/report.  Is there a way to wait until the form loads before launching the PrintDialog?

Code excerpt:

this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
   this.reportViewer1.PrintDialog();

UPDATE

Solution is (as suggested):

```
private void form_load(...)
{
    createReport;
    this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
}

private void reportViewer1_RenderingComplete(...)
{
    this.reportViewer1.PrintDialog();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article suggestions you can't/shouldn't call PrintDialog until the RenderingComplete event fires:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportviewer.renderingcomplete(v=vs.80).aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsreportcontrols/thread/a8993f3e-7787-4e0a-b32f-fcfbf8df8001/